# DELL OptiPlex 7040 BIOS update fails

Tags: 18.04, updates, dell, bios

I'm running DELL OptiPlex 7040 (Ubuntu 18.04.2) and recently a 0.1.14.0 bios update arrived. It's description is:

> This stable release fixes the following issues:
>    • Firmware updates to address security advisory INTEL-SA-00185 (CVE-2018-12188 CVE-2018-12190 CVE-2018-12191 CVE-2018-12192 CVE-2018-12199 CVE-2018-12198 CVE-2018-12200 CVE-2018-12187 CVE-2018-12196 CVE-2018-12185).

After reboot it just hangs
[image]

Luckily rebooting loads system without problems. There were no issues with previous updates. If anyone has any insights, thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried doing in manualy via
`fwupdmgr update`
but it fails the same way, just different file name is displayed

Comment: what happens if you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean && sudo update grub && sudo reboot` ?

Comment: it has no chance of fixing that unfortunately